# Law of a geometric brownian motion first hitting time (formula dont match Monte Carlo Simulation)

Tags: stochastic-processes, monte-carlo, probability, barrier, stopping

I posted this question before on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/946968/law-of-a-geometric-brownian-motion-first-hitting-time-proof-checking)

> I need to use it in a small step in the middle of a simulation and
>   I think I'm not getting correct results to this probabilities and so
>   for my all subsequent simulation.
>        Could someone please check my results and my proof below?

I would like to obtain the law of the first hitting time of a geometric Brownian motion.

More precisely, to compute $\mathbb P [\tau_B \leq T]$ where $$\tau_B := \inf\{0 \leq t \leq T: X_t \leq B \}$$

and $X = (X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a geometric brownian motion of drift  $\mu$ and volatility $\sigma$ with initial condition $X_0> B$.

It's known that it can be obtained in terms of the law of the minimum/maximum of a drifted  Brownian motion.

Indeed,  since $X_t = X_0 \exp ((\mu -\frac{\sigma^2}{2})t + \sigma W_t  )$ and $\{\tau_B\leq T\}= \{X_T^*\leq B\}$ where $X^* = (X_t^*)_{t \geq 0}$ defined by $X^*_t =\min_{t \in [0,T]} X_t$, one can write

\begin{align}
\mathbb P [\tau_B \leq T]&= \mathbb P [X_T^*\leq B]\\
               &= \mathbb P \left[\xi_T^{(\lambda)}\leq \ln \left(\frac{B}{X_0}\right)\right]
\end{align}

where $\xi_t^{(\lambda)}=\min_{s \in [0,t] }\{\bar{\mu} t+\sigma W_t \}= \min_{s \in [0,t] }\{\lambda t + W_t \}$ (last equality comes by scaling) with $\bar{\mu}=(\mu -\frac{\sigma^2}{2}) $ and $\lambda=\frac{\bar{\mu}}{\sigma^2}$.

Then one can just use the formula (see [here](http://famille-chazal.pagesperso-orange.fr/articles/maxbrownien.pdf) for reference, the proof is a straightforward application of Girsanov theorem)

$$\mathbb P \left[\Lambda_T^{(\eta)}\geq x\right]=e^{2\eta x}\mathcal N\left(\frac{-x-\eta t}{\sqrt t}\right)+\mathcal N\left(\frac{-x+\eta t}{\sqrt t}\right)$$

for the law of the maximum of the drifted Brownian motion $\Lambda_t^{(\eta)} := \max_{s \in [0,t] }\{\eta t+W_t \}$. 
Therefore since by symmetry  $\Lambda_t^{(\eta)}\overset{\mathcal L} {=} -\xi_t^{(-\eta)}$ where $\xi_t^{(\eta)} :=\min_{s \in [0,t] }\{\eta t+ W_t \}$ is the minimum of the drifted brownian motion, one can can obtain the following formula

\begin{align}
\mathbb P [\tau_B \leq T]&= \mathbb P [X_T^*\leq B]\\
               &= \mathbb P \left[\xi_T^{(\lambda)}\leq \ln \left(\frac{B}{X_0}\right)
\right]
\\
  &= \mathbb P \left[-\Lambda_T^{(-\lambda)}\leq \ln \left(\frac{B}{X_0}\right)
\right]
\\
&=e^{2\lambda \ln \left(\frac{B}{X_0}\right)}\mathcal N\left(\frac{ \ln \left(\frac{B}{X_0}\right)+\sigma^2 \lambda T}{\sigma \sqrt T}\right)+\mathcal N\left(\frac{ \ln \left(\frac{B}{X_0}\right)-\sigma^2 \lambda  T}{\sigma \sqrt T}\right)\\
&=\left(\frac{B}{X_0}\right)^{2\lambda}\mathcal N\left(\frac{ \ln \left(\frac{B}{X_0}\right)+\bar{\mu} T}{\sigma \sqrt T}\right)+\mathcal N\left(\frac{ \ln \left(\frac{B}{X_0}\right)-\bar{\mu}  T}{\sigma \sqrt T}\right)
\end{align}

Please let me know if you notice any mistake.

I'm having values bigger than one and an unexpected shape for the function $f(B) := \mathbb P [\tau_B \leq T]$ as you can see below in the graphic (Axes $y =f(B)$ and $x =B$; here X_0= 68).

I forced it to be 1 for barrier values equal or higher than the initial value. Nonetheless I think there is still a problem with the formula not only it should be automatically 1 for $B \leq X_0$. The probabilities I have calculating it by Monte Carlo are higher than the values obtained by this formula as you can see in the second graphic bellow.

Many thanks

[image]
[image]

Comment: An interesting reference using similar arguments seems to be "How Likely is it to Hit a Barrier? Thoretical and Emperical Estimates" by Lujing Su and Marc Oliver Rieger.

Comment: You do not post your implementation, but I am guessing that you check the values of drifted Brownian motion at some prespecified time points $\delta t, 2 \delta t, ..., N \delta t$. If so, you will be overestimating the probability that $\tau_b<T$ because you do not take into account the situations where $ n \delta t > B$, $(n+1) \delta t > B$ but $\tau \in [ n \delta t, (n+1) \delta t]$.  You can check if my guess is correct by reducing $\delta t$

Comment: @YuliaV: Thanks a lot for your hint. You suppose you meant $X_{n\delta t}> B$ and $X_{(n+1) \delta t}> B$, right? In this case I would be underestimating the probability of hitting the barrier before $T$ instead of overestimating it since I'm excluding a lot of paths in with the condition is satisfied. Am I right ?

Comment: @Paul, yes, you are right, sorry, I have misunderstood the value you were simulating. Yet, posting your code and reducing $\delta t$ might help - would you try it?

Comment: @YuliaV: If I am underestimating it reducing $\delta t $ would just increase the difference between the values computed by the closed formula and those via Monte Carlo. I don't see how it could help. I'm running the simulation with a $\delta t $ 10 times smaller anyway. I am pretty much convinced that if there is a mistake of my part (and it's clearly the case) it is almost surely in the closed formula. So you you guys could check it would be great. I've done that uncountable times and after so many tries our looking on it is so biased that it's too hard to detect a simple mistake.

Comment: @Paul - checking your code, reducing the time step, increasing the number of paths and eventually estimating the MonteCarlo error are the usual sanity checks. Posting your code might be helpful.

Comment: @YuliaV: You are absolutly right ! Of course I'm going to post it as soon as I have time to prepare it (change a little bit the notation for clarity sake). Anyway what about the formula ? Is there any mistake ? I think it's fundamental to check it also. And it's much quicker than check, run and eventually debug a code.

Comment: Can it be the case that you mixed up the normal density  and the normal cdf?

Comment: @James: Thanks for your comment. That is not the case. However I just found a mistake in the transcription of the closed formula my code. I've written $\left(\frac{B}{X0} \right)^{2 \bar{\mu}}$ instead of $\left(\frac{B}{X0} \right)^{2 {\lambda}}$ which explain the scaling difference. Now the match is perfect!

Comment: Hi Paul, welcome to Quant.SE! Good to hear you found your solution. Can you put it as an answer? Then it's clear this question is solved.